# Can R connect to an ssl-protected MongoDB instance?

Tags: r, mongodb, rmongodb

Can't find docs on this. No problem from Python but I cannot see an ssl option in the rmongodb library.

```
> mongo <- mongo.create("xx.xx.xx.xx", name = "someuser", password = "thepassword", db = "admin")
Unable to connect to replset
```

Are there any alternative libraries that support ssl for R connection to mongodb? Does rmongodb do so but I have missed something?

Comment: I added this [issue](https://github.com/mongosoup/rmongodb/issues/67) and will check it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the error is due to just writing the function arguments incorrectly. Just take a look at the help file of `?mongo.create` again.

```
# Being explicit
mongo <- mongo.create("xx.xx.xx.xx", name='', username = "someuser", 
                      password = "thepassword", db = "admin")
```

Now you should be getting another type of error or it works.